# I can't load data to DataTable with AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm building an Asp.net Core project with N-tier architecture. I'm using DataTable and I want to load data with Ajax but I'm overlooking some things. This is my code;

My View;

```html
<script type ="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: "/api/Values",
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "Id" },
                { data: "Name" },
                { data: "Description" },
                { data: "Date" },
                { data: "Deleted" },
                {
                    data: "id",
                    render: function (data, type, row,meta) {
                        return "<button class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-right:5px;' onclick=Edit("+ JSON.stringify(row) +")>Edit</button>" +
                            "<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick=Delete("+ JSON.stringify(row) +")>Delete</button>";
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

My API Controller code;

```html
namespace MottoUI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        RoleManager rm = new RoleManager(new EfRoleRepository());
        IRoleService _roleService = null;

        public ValuesController(IRoleService roleService)
        {
            _roleService = roleService;
        }

        // GET: api/<ValuesController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Role> GetRole()
        {
            return _roleService.GetList();
        }
}
```

My Entity structure;

```html
public class Role
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    }
```

I got this error;

[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQhfv.jpg)

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Can you share your model structure and check if your response code is 200 ?If you try to use `{ data: "id" }, { data: "name" },{ data: "description" },{ data: "date" },{ data: "deleted" },`,will the error be solved?

Comment: This does not fix my problem man, I fix the different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As per the error you have shared on the screenshots which means you either missing `myTable` Id reference on your `button` or you
> are not adding the `cdn` reference which you are using on your
> `Javascript code`. You should add below referece at the begining of your `Javascript code`:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

**Controller:**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Role> GetRole()
        {
            var roleList = new List<Role>()
            {
                new Role(){ Id = 1,Name ="Plan A", Description= "Plan Description A", Date=DateTime.Now,Deleted= true},
                new Role(){ Id = 2,Name ="Plan B", Description= "Plan Description B", Date=DateTime.Now,Deleted= false},
                new Role(){ Id = 3,Name ="Plan C", Description= "Plan Description C", Date=DateTime.Now,Deleted= true},
                new Role(){ Id = 4,Name ="Plan D", Description= "Plan Description D", Date=DateTime.Now,Deleted= false},
                new Role(){ Id = 5,Name ="Plan E", Description= "Plan Description E", Date=DateTime.Now,Deleted= true},


            };
             return roleList;
        }
}
```

**View:**

```
<h2>BindDataTableFromJson</h2>
<table id="bindDataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Deleted</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://localhost:7132/api/Values/",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $('#bindDataTable').DataTable({
                        data: response,
                        columns: [
                            { data: 'id' },
                            { data: 'name' },
                            { data: 'description' },
                            { data: 'date' },
                            { data: 'deleted' }
                            
                        ]
                    });

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

> **`Note:`** Your this code snippet also has issue. Please make sure that you have not missed anything obvious.

```
{
    data: "id", render: function (data, type, row,meta) {
    return "<button class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-right:5px;' onclick=Edit("+ JSON.stringify(row) +")>Edit</button>" +
```

"<button class='btn btn-danger' onclick=Delete("+ JSON.stringify(row) +")>Delete";
}
},

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Glad to assist you .