# Datatables.net table is not showing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, datatable

I am trying to use datatables.net by copying the CDN download method.I am using ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) with mvc

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuYKd.png)

and adding a Javascript item like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('myTable').DataTable({
        "scrollY": "450px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging": true
    });

});
```

But the Datatable functionalities is not showing on my table and I get this error:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNdgg.png)

Comment: Could you please share your details `code snippet` and how did you added the `datatable` reference? Its also important. You could [`have a look the example here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71965631/i-cant-load-data-to-datatable-with-ajax/71966432#71966432)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided the markup but you might be missing a '#' before myTable so try
$('#myTable').DataTable ....
if 'myTable' is your element's id;